# accessing arrays stored in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe in which one column contains 1-D numpy arrays and another contains scalar data for instance:

```
df =
    A   B
0   x   [0, 1, 2]
1   y   [0, 1, 2]
2   z   [0, 1, 2]
```

I want to get B for the row where `A=='x'` So I tried `df[df.A == 'x'].B.values` which gives me the output:

```
array([array([0, 1, 2])], dtype=object)
```

The output has an extra `array([])` around it. I get that Pandas is treating it like an object and not just data, and I have a way to access the array by using `df[df.A == 'x'].B.values[0]` instead. In the case of scalar data I can just use the syntax `df[df.A == 'x'].B` which is a lot cleaner than the `df[df.A == 'x'].B.values[0]` which I have to use.

My question is: is there a better/cleaner/shorter way to access the data in the format I put it in? or is this just something I will have to live with?

Comment: or you can use...`df[df.A==10].B.item()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference isn't the fact that the array is an object, but that the query you specify could return more than one object (hence the outer array()). If you're confident that the query will return only a single object, then you can use @Wen 's solution to use `.item()`:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([
   ...: dict(A='x', B=[0,1,2]),
   ...: dict(A='y', B=[0,1,2]),
   ...: dict(A='z', B=[0,1,2]),
   ...: ])

In [3]: df[df.A == 'x'].B.item()
Out[3]: [0, 1, 2]
```

But based on the kind of query, you should at least consider checking the results to make sure:

```
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame([
   ...: dict(A='x', B=[0,1,2]),
   ...: dict(A='y', B=[0,1,2]),
   ...: dict(A='z', B=[0,1,2]),
   ...: dict(A='x', B=[3,3,3]),
   ...: ])

In [5]: df[df.A == 'x'].B.item()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-e0ad528e719e> in <module>()
----> 1 df[df.A == 'x'].B.item()

   ...

ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar

In [6]: df[df.A == 'x'].B.values
Out[6]: array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 3, 3]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`squeeze`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) method. If your result after applying your filter only contains one row, it will return the contents of the row, because it converts it 1 dimension lower.

```
In[103]: df = pd.DataFrame([['x', [1, 2, 3]], ['y', [1, 2, 3]], ['y', [1, 2, 3]]], index=[0, 1, 2], columns=['A', 'B'])
In[104]: df
Out[104]: 
   A          B
0  x  [1, 2, 3]
1  y  [1, 2, 3]
2  y  [1, 2, 3]

In[105]: df[df.A == 'x'].B.squeeze()
Out[105]: [1, 2, 3]

In[106]: df[df.A == 'y'].B.squeeze()
Out[106]: 
1    [1, 2, 3]
2    [1, 2, 3]
Name: B, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `loc` you will get different objects depending on the indexers you've passed.  In your example:

```
df.loc[df.A == 'x', 'B']
```

you passed `df.A == 'x'` which returns a `pd.Series` of boolean values.  Since this is an array like input, you are guaranteed to get output that expands the index dimension.

Now because the second indexer was a scalar `'B'`, you will not expand the columns dimension.  Thus what is output is a `pd.Series` object whose index consists of all the index values in which the boolean series `df.A == 'x'` was `True` and whose name is `'B'`

```
0    [1, 2, 3]
Name: B, dtype: object
```

**In short** this has nothing to do with having arrays in column `'B'`

---

**Option 1**
Get a scalar result from `df.A == 'x'`

```
df.loc[df.A.eq('x').idxmax(), 'B']

[1, 2, 3]
```

---

**Option 2**
Set the index

```
df.set_index('A').B.loc['x']

[1, 2, 3]
```

---

**Option 3**
Tricky Dict
I'm not really serious about this option.  I just thought it was cool. As mentioned in the comments, there are many things that can go wrong with it.

```
dict(df.values)['x']

[1, 2, 3]
```

However, with a slight modification, we can improve the robustness.

```
dict(df[['A', 'B']].values)['x']
```

Comment: I like that tricky dict, but it's super sensitive to the layout of the DF. It'd be a bit more general purpose if you did `dict(df[['A', 'B']].values)['x']`. Option 2 is probably the best one overall if this operation needs to be done multiple times.