# lookup first match in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to use a DataFrame as a lookup table on columns that are not part of the index. For example (this is a simple one just to illustrate):

```
import pandas as pd

westcoast = pd.DataFrame([['Washington','Olympia'],['Oregon','Salem'],
                          ['California','Sacramento']],
                        columns=['state','capital'])
print westcoast

        state     capital
0  Washington     Olympia
1      Oregon       Salem
2  California  Sacramento
```

It's easy to lookup and get a Series as an output:

```
westcoast[westcoast.state=='Oregon'].capital

1    Salem
Name: capital, dtype: object
```

but I want to obtain the string 'Salem':

```
westcoast[westcoast.state=='Oregon'].capital.values[0]

'Salem'
```

and the `.values[0]` seems somewhat clunky... is there a better way?

(FWIW: my real data has maybe 50 rows at most, but lots of columns, so if I do set an index column, no matter what column I choose, there will be a lookup operation like this that is not based on an index, and the relatively small number of rows means that I don't care if it's O(n) lookup.)

Comment: you can check the answer there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352688/accessing-arrays-stored-in-pandas-dataframe#comment79665647_46352688

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`Series.item`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.item.html) if the lookup will always returns one element from the `Series`:

```
westcoast.loc[westcoast.state=='Oregon', 'capital'].item()
```

Exceptions can be handled if the lookup returns nothing, or one or more values and you need only the first item:

```
s = westcoast.loc[westcoast.state=='Oregon', 'capital']
s = np.nan if s.empty else s.iat[0] 
print (s) #Salem

s = westcoast.loc[westcoast.state=='New York', 'capital']
s = np.nan if s.empty else s.iat[0] 
print (s)
nan
```

A more general solution to handle the exceptions because there are 3 possible output scenarios:

```
westcoast = pd.DataFrame([['Washington','Olympia'],['Oregon','Salem'],
                          ['California','Sacramento'],['Oregon','Portland']],
                        columns=['state','capital'])

print (westcoast)
        state     capital
0  Washington     Olympia
1      Oregon       Salem
2  California  Sacramento
3      Oregon    Portland

s = westcoast.loc[westcoast.state=='Oregon', 'capital']

#if not value returned
if s.empty:
    s = 'no match'

#if only one value returned
elif len(s) == 1:
    s = s.item()
else:

# if multiple values returned, return a list of values
    s = s.tolist()

print (s)
['Salem', 'Portland']
```

It is possible to create a lookup function:

```
def look_up(a):
    s = westcoast.loc[westcoast.state==a, 'capital']
    #for no match
    if s.empty:
        return np.nan
    #for match only one value
    elif len(s) == 1:
        return s.item()
    else:
    #for return multiple values
        return s.tolist()

print (look_up('Oregon'))
['Salem', 'Portland']

print (look_up('California'))
Sacramento

print (look_up('New Yourk'))
nan
```

Comment: oh good -- for some reason whenever I pore through the pandas docs there are little hidden aspects of this that I'm not aware of. Thanks! https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.item.html#pandas.Series.item

Comment: why the `.loc` btw? is it better?

Comment: Yes, `loc` is faster if larger data.

Comment: Hmm.... it seems bad return an intermediate series just to get at one item (in the case of duplicates in the index). Isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to do frequent lookups of this sort, then it pays to make `state` the index:

```
state_capitals = westcoast.set_index('state')['capital']
print(state_capitals['Oregon'])
# Salem
```

With an index, each lookup is `O(1)` on average, whereas `westcoast['state']=='Oregon'` requires `O(n)` comparisons. Of course, building the index is also `O(n)`, so you would need to do many lookups for this to pay off.

At the same time, once you have `state_capitals` the syntax is simple and dict-like. That might be reason enough to build `state_capitals`.